# Solve in terms of $ln(5)$ and $ln(3)$: $15^{4y}=3^{4y+8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Here is my attempt, and I don't understand why it doesn't work (I apologise for my clunky MathJax):

$(4y)ln15=(4y+8)ln3$

$(4y)(ln3+ln5)=(4y+8)ln3$

$4(y(ln3+ln5)=4(y+2ln3)$

$y(ln3+ln5)=(y+2ln3)$

$y(ln3+ln5)-y=(2ln3)$

$y(ln3+ln5-1)=(2ln3)$

$y=\frac{2ln3}{ln3+ln5-1}$

The correct answer, however, is $\frac{2ln3}{ln5}$. Could someone point to my mistake, as I can't recognise it myself? Thank you.

Comment: If the original problem is indeed $(\ln 15)^{4y}=(\ln 3)^{4y+8}$, the next line should then be $$4y\ln(\ln3+\ln5)=(4y+8)\ln(\ln 3).$$ The only way the second line is $4y\ln15=(4y+8)\ln3$ is if the original problem was instead $15^{4y}=3^{4y+8}$. You should check if your title is correct or not.

Comment: @arctictern You are correct, the title is wrong. Thank you and I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: Typesetting hint: put a backslash before `ln` to make it display in roman type (`\ln x` gives $\ln x$, while `ln x` gives $ln x$). The same goes for `\sin`, `\cos`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

$$4y(\ln3+\ln5)=4(y+2\color{red})\ln3$$

$$y(\ln 3 + \ln 5) = (y+2) \ln 3$$

$$y\ln 5 = 2\ln 3$$

Comment: Are you interpreting the original problem as $15^{4y}=3^{4y+8}$? If so, you should be clear and explicit when you believe an OP has incorrectly posed a problem and how you're reinterpreting it.

Comment: I am intepreting it as $15^{4y}=3^{4y+8}$.

Answer (score 2):

Mistake is in step $2$ and $3$ $$(4y+8)\ln 3\ne 4(y+2\ln3)$$

Answer (score 1):

i think it must be $$4y(\ln(3)+\ln(5))=(4y+8)\ln(3)$$